# Excel - Can I create a list of values with criteria and have excel make a list with parameters?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In Excel, I am trying to see how many combinations I can make with the allotted criteria and such.

So lets say I want to know how many combinations of groceries I want to buy for a certain budget. Lets say my total budget is $100.

I want to buy 1 grain item, 2 produce items, 3 beverages, 1 meat, 1 sweet. These would be a "basket" of groceries.

In each column I would list

Column A - Grains

Grain - Price

Different Grain - Price

etc etc

Column B - Produce

Repeat

I then want excel to help me decide how many different basket combinations I could create at the grocery while staying under my budget.

Any ideas?

Thanks!